# Creating a client which can interact with asterisk manager using node.js

Tags: node.js, asterisk

I have a node.js server, what I want is that the same server should run as a client for asterisk manager and can connect to AM using node.js.

The overall architecture will be like this :

Client interact with node.js server.
The same server acts as a client to asterisk manager.
Asterisk manager will provide data to client(which is also a node.js server)
Now the node.js server will push data to its actual client.

Comment: ...and you came here so that somebody writes this for you? And that you can get paid for other people's work?

Comment: I really don't want to get paid for others work, I want that if anyone have any link which can help me in my stuff he/she can share it here, that is what this platform is developed for.

Comment: My point is this: All you did is post a bunch of requirements with no code of your own whatsoever. This is not how this website works. We are here to help you with specific problems in your own code. We are not here to develop a working system according to some written spec. (We are also not here to Google links for you.) So either you post code you have, along with a description of what *specific* problems you have with it, or your question isn't a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: okay, I got what you are saying. I'll edit my post once I have written enough code to make you people understand what I really want. thanks

Comment: This question should be closed for being overly broad and lacking in sufficient details to be answered with clarity.  The question is unlikely to be of any value to the community.

Answer (score 0):

It's too difficult to get a nodejs compatible client, probably you will have to build a complete module which is compatible with nodejs.
My requirement was also the same, I would suggest instead of looking for any nodejs module use sipml5 client with asterisk. The audio part can be handled with sipml5 and other features can be built with nodejs.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

I'm writing similar app by nodejs.
Use `asterisk-ami` npm module so you can connect to your asterisk server and access required events.

Here's the link for the described module:
[here's the link for the described module.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asterisk-ami)